# alerting the user of "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this in ASP.NET 4 webforms.
Now I know the user sends HTML in the textbox. my problem is that I want to alert him that he entered HTML and invalid content.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `validateRequest="false"` will avoid this error, but it will leave the page vulnerable to a number of attacks which may be sql injection attacks also.
Or use `HTMLEncode` on all fields where you are taking input.

For more detailed explanation have a look at following `Stackoverflow question` about handling suspicious content:

[A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to [Parse the HTML Content](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/htmlparser.aspx) entered by the user in your browser.